# Compare GregorianCalendar time with current time

Tags: android, calendar, compare

this is My Events time:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1454970600000,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=6,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=40,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=4,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

i am setting my event time as:

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date = data.get(i).getSchdDate();
String hour = data.get(i).getFromTime();

try {
    startTime.setTime(sdf.parse(date + " " + hour));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and now i want to know if this time  is smaller than the current time or not? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that calendar is in a variable called cal:

```
if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: check the edit i have posted the code snippet for setting time

Comment: @Newbiee it doesn't matter how you set your Calendar (unless you care doing it incorrectly).  The Calendar represents an absolute point in time.  Just compare it like I have shown.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Comparing times in millis like this doesn't require a knowledge of timezone.  These are absolute points in time for all people on earth that share the same point of reference for time = 0.

Comment: @DougStevenson You're right. I've always (wrongly) assumed that `System.currentTimeMillis()` would return local time, but it seems that it does not.